# Who are the two thieves that appear the opening of Batman: TAS?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

In the *Batman: The Animated Series* [opening](https://youtu.be/ivU_GxS6he4?t=13), two villains are seen blowing up a bank, and Batman confronts and captures them for the police.

**Have the two villains appeared in an episode? Are they just thieves used in the opening?**

Comment: I think it's just a generic duo of villains. But that's speculation hence why I'm commenting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original storyboards describe them as

> "Hoods".

Hood(lum) #1 and Hood(lum) #2 don't appear to have actual names and don't seem to appear in any subsequent episodes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, there's a fun description of just how well-designed the opening is at https://comicsalliance.com/ask-chris-78-why-the-batman-the-animated-series-opening-is/?trackback=fbshare_mobile

Comment: These are the best-drawn storyboards I've ever seen. Not a single stick figure.